# Django FormPreview and ImageField, Image not displayed

Tags: python, django

Have form.

```
class AddLogo(forms.Form):

    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = forms.TimeField()
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

And have standard Django preview form.

```
from django.contrib.formtools.preview import FormPreview
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from company.models import Company

class add_logo_preview(FormPreview):

    form_template = 'add_logo_preview.html'

    def done(self, request, cleaned_data):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/company/hey/')
```

In template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block block_js %}
{% endblock block_js %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Preview your submission</h1>

{% with form as job %}
<div class="job_block">
    <div class="job_content">
        <div class="job_title">
            <h1>{{ job.title.data }}</h1>
            <span class="date">{{ job.date.date.data }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="job_company">
            <div class="company_logo">
                {{ job.image.url }}
            </div>
            <div class="company_description">
                <div class="name">{{ job.company_name.data }}</div>
                <div class="location">Главный офис: {{ job.company_location.data }}</div>
                <div class="website"><a href="{{ job.company_url.data }}">{{ job.company_url.data }}</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <article>
            {{ job.description.data|safe }}
        </article>
    </div>
    <aside>
        <h4>Поделиться вакансией</h4>
    </aside>
</div>
<div class="job_feedback">
    <h3>Откликнутся на вакансию</h3>
    <p>{{ job.apply_terms.data|safe }}</p>
</div>
{% endwith %}

<p>Security hash: {{ hash_value }}</p>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}{{ field.as_hidden }}
{% endfor %}
<input type="hidden" name="{{ stage_field }}" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="{{ hash_field }}" value="{{ hash_value }}" />
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>

<h1>Or edit it again</h1>

<h1>Шаг первый: создайте свое объявление</h1>

<form action="/job/preview/" method="POST" class="form">{% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Опишите вакансию</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="label_box">
            <label for="">Назавние вакансии</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fields_box">
            {{ form.title }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="label_box">
            <label for="">Категория</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fields_box">
            {% for cat in form.category %}
                {% if cat.choice_value %}
                {{ cat }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="label_box">
            <label for="">Головной офис</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fields_box">
            {{ form.company_location }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="one_col">
        <div class="label_box">
            <label for="">
                Описание вакансии
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="fields_box">
            {{ form.description }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="label_box">
            <label for="">
                Apply this job.
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="fields_box">
            {{ form.apply_terms }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <h3>О компании</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="label_box">
            <label for="">Название</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fields_box">
            {{ form.company_name }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="label_box">
            <label for="">Логотип</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fields_box">
            {{ form.image }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="label_box">
            <label for="">URL</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fields_box">
            {{ form.company_url }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="label_box">
            <label for="">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fields_box">
            {{ form.company_email }}
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="label_box">
            <span>
                Подсветить это объявление?
            </span>
            <label for="">{{ form.highlight }} Подсветить?</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Просмотреть">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I try: {{ form.image.url }} but does not work. I understand one: Django do not upload file, but how i cane change this? How i can make preview image in django FormPreview?

Comment: can u show ur full form in html template ?, also we should provide atleast one argument for ImageField Class lile ImageField(upload_to="folder") ?

Comment: https://www.monosnap.com/image/wYL6fWrFtywGPDzY712OlG4nM this displayed if i add upload_to="folder".

Answer (score 1):

Convert your image to a base64 string, add a field to your form for that base 64 string. In the preview template, display the base64 string. And when finally saving the image, you will need to create a file, write the content of the base 64 string to it, and then save that file to your model.